# ASP.NET datagrid Footer like Header

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a datatable that I introduce into a Datagrid. I want that the Datagrid have, for each column, the same text in the footer than the header. After some search and try, I wasn't able to code it.

My idea would be something like this:

```
    foreach (DataGridColumn columna in DataGrid2.Columns)
        columna.FooterText = columna.HeaderText;
```

Thank you for the help :)

---

I got it!!! (more or less xDD). First of all thank you for your answers :)

I explain what I did here, so it could be interesting for someone, or if anybody can help improve it.

- Inside  the asp:Datagrid I add this 'OnItemDataBound="DataGrid1_rellenarFooter"'
- And on the code page associated to this html I add the next function:

  ```
  protected void DataGrid1_rellenarFooter(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
      {
          e.Item.Cells[0].Text = "Estado";
          e.Item.Cells[1].Text = "Modelo";
          e.Item.Cells[2].Text = "Nº de Serie";
          e.Item.Cells[3].Text = "Descripción";
      }
  }
  ```

I add the footer of each column manually ("Estado", "Modelo", "Nº de Serie", "Descripción"). I would like to introduce from the name of each column, but haven't been able to do it.

Thank you again for your help and hope this can help anybody else. If you have any idea on how to take the name of each column header, answer here.

Comment: Have you tried the code you have? What happens?

Comment: @stuartd I tryed, but it does nothing

Comment: Which `DataGrid` are we talking about? The ancient one in Windows Forms or the ASP.NET one? Is the footer actually set to be visible at all?

Comment: @s.m. Don't know, it's inside a form, it start with this: <asp:DataGrid  ID="DataGrid2" ...  The footer is visible, I can see it, but it's empty. I just see a green empty row at the end of the datagrid

Comment: Ok then, better to specify you're talking about ASP.NET.

Comment: @s.m. Specified, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: No problem, I can't help you with this specific issue but someone else might if the question is properly tagged :)

Comment: @s.m. Ok, I hope someone can help me, should I specify something more? And thank you for your help :)

Comment: Use `DataGrid2_ItemDataBinding` handler. `if(e.Item.ItemType ==Footer)...`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev could you explain a bit more please? I'm starting with asp.net

Comment: Read for example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx